# Как сделать независимую от магазина страницу оплаты товара на сайте?

Tags: php, modx, minishop2, платежи

Всем привет!

**Задача**: реализовать следующий функционал. 
На сайте имеется форма оставления заявки на определенный товар, например, на определенный тур. 
Рядом с описанием товара имеется кнопка "Забронировать" или "Оставить заявку", не суть важно. Суть в том, что после нажатия человек вводит контактные данные и они улетают компании. 
Далее компания обрабатывает эти данные и в ответ должна прислать уникальную ссылку клиенту для оплаты этого товара через систему онлайн-платежей.

Соответственно, вопрос в следующем: как грамотно реализовать такую модель взаимодействия на сайте? 
Единственный и, мне кажется, достаточно абсурдный вариант, который пока пришел мне в голову - передавать через GET-параметры параметр вроде идентификатора товара или номера заявки, который бы генерировался автоматически.

Как же все-таки это на самом деле работает?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю можно сделать в этом направлении:

1. При отправке данных клиентом, создается какой-нибудь рандомный id заказа, который сохраняется в базе вместе с id товара, его кол-вом и подобной инфой, а также пометкой - "не оплачен".
2. Далее компания отправляет ссылку, в которой есть данный id(тот же GET, почему бы и нет) на почту клиента.
3. Клиент переходит по данной ссылке. Ну и по id считывается из базы что он заказал и вперед на оплату.
4. После оплаты для данного id ставим отметку - оплачен.

Можно еще добавить время, за которое клиент должен успеть оплатить и написать простой cron который будет удалять все записи из бд, старше этого времени.